# Group objects based on multiple properties

Tags: java

I want to group/collect objects based on some properties. The project has some Product objects:

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private ProductFlavor flavor; // enum
    private ProductType productType; // enum
    private ProductCategory category; // enum
}
```

What I know need to do is make a collection so that the products are combined per Category and per category are combined per productType and then show all possible flavors for that product.

So for example

- Product 1 has Category 1 and is of type cookie and has flavor vanilla
- Product 2 has Category 2 and is of type biscuits and has flavor strawberry
- Product 3 has Category 1 and is of type cookie and has flavor chocolate

To visualize this is a product table that should in this case contain

- Cookie with a dropdown vanille and chocolate
- Biscuits with a dropdown strawberry

I started with grouping them by category but then I'm stuck. Because to me it should be a List of product categories with grouped products with possible flavors.

```
Map<ProductCategory, List<Product>> result = dummies.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
                Product::getCategory,
                TreeMap::new,
                Collectors.mapping(event -> event, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
        )
);
```

Comment: do Category and ProductType always match? that is, in your example Category 1 is always related to cookie, if that is true, then you already have your answer because grouping by category will result also in a group by product type, if not, you can perform and additional grouping to the List of Product inside the Map, then you will have something like `Map<ProductCategory, Map<ProductType, List<Product>>`

Comment: No that is indeed not the case. Will try to do the extra mapping.

Answer (score 1):

*is that what You need?*

```
   Map<ProductFlavor,Map<ProductCategory,List<Product>>> byFlavor = products.stream()
        .collect( groupingBy( p -> p.flavor, groupingBy( c -> c.category ) ) );
```

`flavor` and `category` must be made accessible or You define getters